# Exception from MVC API to MVC site gives error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created an MVC (4) Web API which works fine. It has a simple login-method that throws an exception when the user cannot be found.

Besides the API I created a simple website that calls the API by HttpClient:

```
public T ExecutePost<T>(string apiUrl, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData) {
    HttpContent content = null;

    if (postData != null)
        content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

    var a = _client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).ContinueWith(httpResponseMessage => 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(httpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
    );

   return a.Result;
}
```

You can call this method as

```
ExecutePost<User>("url_to_controller_action_api", list_with_keys_and_values_to_post)
```

When this method calls the API with the postData-fiels username and password (both are correct and known by the system) an object called User will be returned... Works like a charm.
When I call this method with the wrong username and/or password, the API throws an exception (User not found), but the method ExecutePost throws an exception aswell and the web page shows a nice, yellow-isch, red-letter page with errors that the normal user does not understand. The reason is easy: The data sent back from the API is not the same as the data that can be put in the object User.

So, what I would like to do is deserialize the exception, from the API, in an object called Error and return that to the controller of the MVC website, so I can put the error "User not found" on the page with the correct design of the site.

What is the best way to do this? Try-catch in all actions? Doesn't feel right to me... So suggestions are more than welcome.

Most things I found were API-side stuff, but I want to fetch and handle the exception on the site-side.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than throwing exceptions around the boundaries, I would follow the restful approach and have the web-api return a status code that matches your exception requirements.  so for user not found, a 404.  have your httpclient read the status code and then react accordingly, either deserialise the json or show the error.

Answer (score 1):

On your Web API when you detect an invalid login, make sure that an `HttpResponseException` gets thrown with a status code of 401 (`HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`).

```
//login failed:
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Invalid Username or password")
                };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

In your calling code, you can then first check if `httpResponseMessage.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.OK` before you attempt to deserialise the response into a `User`.

```
var a = _client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).ContinueWith(httpResponseMessage => {
if (httpResponseMessage.Status!=HttpStatus.OK)
{
     string ErrorMessage = httpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     //and whatever you want to do with that error message here
}
else
{ 
 try
    {
       var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(httpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //honest to goodness unrecoverable failure on the webapi.
        //all you can do here is fail gracefully to the caller.
    }
}//endif (Status OK)
}//end anonymous function
);
```

If it's not a 200 then you can execute a second check to see if it's a 401 (and have some specific handling for invalid login) or a more general 500 (something went wrong on the server), etc, and get the actual error message of the exception ("Invalid Username or password") to send back to the client:

`var errorMessage = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Finally, even if it is 200 then you should still `try...catch` the deserialisation operation so you can gracefully handle any issues with the returned data, if for whatever reason the data can't be turned into a `User` object.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. But... In the controller I do: var user = GetUserFromAPI(username, password). The method GetUserFromAPI calls the code as shown in my first post and it expects an object User returned. When httpResponseMessage.StatusCode!=HttpStatusCode.OK, how can I use that in the controller? Like ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username/password incorrect"); Other errors can be: User blocked, pending activation

Comment: See my edited answer above; either use that pattern or else modify the webapi so that it doesn't throw an exception when user is not found, but instead returns a User object with some kind of detectable "bad" state. But you still need to try/catch the deserialisation just in case...I don't see any other way to do it?